# SQL Query to find the common data based on two or more condition from the same table?

Tags: html, sql, database, subquery, report

I have set of country codes and each country has set of accounts holder counts.
I want to fetch the same account numbers along with the country codes among all the countries which are being available in multiple countries.

For example:

[image]

Comment: The same account numbers means  you want fetch all the countries who have the same numbers of accounts ?

Comment: So the total number of accounts shown might have the same account number listed in multiple countries? I feel like we need more table data. Also, what database client are you using?

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you so much for response. Yes, you are correct the same account numbers might be repeating in multiple countries. I don't have much insights regarding data base. I use QMF tool to write SQL queries and I think it is DB2. 
Actually all the country codes and corresponding account numbers are in the same table.

Comment: Both country code and account numbers columns are in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of accounts grouped by country codes:

```
SELECT [Country Code],COUNT([Accounts]) FROM [table] GROUP BY [Country Code]
```